How to import svelte node-adapter build - handler.js, in a different node.js-express-typescript app?
I am new to Svelte and TypeScript.
I have a Svelte + TypeScript project and a different backend project with node.js, express, and TypeScript.
I want to deploy the Svelte app with the backend project I already have.
Following [this] (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-node#custom-server) documentation, I built the Svelte app via npm run build which generated the output in a "build" folder. I copied the "build" folder from the svelte project into my backend project and tried to import the handler.js from my src/app.ts as:
import { handler } from "../build/handler.js";

But the editor is giving me the following error on the import line:

Could not find a declaration file for module '../build/handler.js'. '.../build/handler.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

How to fix this problem? Or am I doing something wrong?

go to your tsconfig.json file and set "allowJs": true.

The error is a TypeScript error, not a runtime error.  This error by itself does not preclude you from importing the handler.  This happens because the built process is not providing a .d.ts file for the handler.  I don't even know if that's available, in all honesty.  You might want to raise the issue with the Svelte guys.

Thanks for the response. I included "allowJs": true in my tsconfig.json as told by Subha and it worked. But I am not sure if this is the optimal solution.

It is not optimal.  Ideally, you get a hold of the types for the handler so us TypeScripters are kept happy.
